# How to implement a runtime debug assertion without macros in C++ 11/14 with type safety?

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, assertion

An assertion to be used in a context like:

```
ASSERT(dynamic_cast<Derived*>(_ptr));
ptr = static_cast<Derived*>(ptr);
```

So during debugging the assertion will check the dynamic cast but will be removed for the release mode. (standard assertion behaviour)

How can I implement this using without macros. What I was thinking was:

```
void ASSERT(bool _arg)
{
    if(!_arg)
        //something
}
```

However, this doesn't ensure type safety. Additionally, I was thinking of having two implementations of this, one which is empty(for release, so the ASSERT function does nothing) and another with the code above for debug. This method would also rely on the compiler optimising out the empty function, something which is not always reliable.

Therefore, what would be the best way to go about it? Or are macros absolutely necessary...?

Comment: I would prefer the macro because it allows you to add additional details like `__LINE__` and `__FILE__`, so in case of an error you know excactly where it occurs. This cannot be done witth a function.

Comment: Consider the following example: `ASSERT(f1() && f2() || f3())` - I'm not sure whether the compiler will optimize the call of `ASSERT` in this case and nevertheless the fx()-function calls will remain. With an empty macro there is nothing left to be called...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The benefit of using macros for this purpose over functions is as you said, there is a chance that the check won't be completely optimised out and you'll still pay for the dynamic_cast.

Your best option is to use `assert(dynamic_cast<Derived*>(_ptr) != nullptr)`. Type safety doesn't buy you anything for assert-like behaviour.

If you must write your own function, you can conditionally call `std::abort` from the `<cstdlib>` header, but you'll have to add any diagnostic information yourself.

Comment: Yes, adding `!=nullptr` is something I considered, but it relies on the user being able to add it, if not it may lead to undefined behaviour, so I wanted to try and avoid it. Guess the user will have to pay attention to the compiler warnings then.

Comment: Adding `!= nullptr` isn't essential. The result of the `dynamic_cast` will be implicitly converted to bool and, if the result is a null pointer, ie. the `dynamic_cast` failed, it will convert to `false` and the assert will trigger.  
edit. Explicitly adding the null pointer check is only beneficial if implicit conversions make you uncomfortable, or if you want the diagnostic to be more explicit.